# How to Automate the SQL repository refresh in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, automation, sql-update, repository

I update Repository in SQL Server using multiple tables, I run the various update, insert query to refresh the repository, now I need to Automate this refresh, What can be the best solution for it Except SSIS.

Comment: Is your question how to schedule a T-SQL script with various insert/update statements? If so, consider a [SQL Server Agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/sql-server-agent) T-SQL job step.

Comment: @DanGuzman no, the question is more like what is an alternative option for SSIS where I can automate my repository refresh process

Comment: Your question doesn't include details of what your repository refresh process is other than it involves running update and insert queries. That doesn't require SSIS.